# Adding event handler (with parameters) to element created using document.createElement

Tags: javascript

In the function below I'm trying to create a dynamic element *(textArea)*. I'm trying to bind a function *(resize)* to the text area using *textArea.onclick = resize;* which works fine.

What I'd like to do is pass a parameter to the resize function (either the generated id or, if possible, the textArea itself)

```
    function addElement(elm, event) {
        var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
        var id = Math.random();
        textArea.setAttribute('id', id)
        textArea.setAttribute('cols', 1);
        textArea.setAttribute('rows', 3);
        textArea.onclick = resize;
        elm.appendChild(textArea);
    }
```

if I say *textArea.onclick = resize(id);* then that just calls the function.

How can i bind the function, and pass a parameter to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a closure:

```
textArea.onclick = function() { resize(id); };
```

Or use the elements id attribute:

```
textArea.onclick = function() { resize(this.id); };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the id, and the textarea from the event object itself. In the resize function, access the textarea, and subsequently the id as:

```
function resize(event) {
    var textarea = event.target;
    var id = textarea.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function called resize from another function.

```
     function addElement(elm, event) {
        var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
        var id = Math.random();
        textArea.setAttribute('id', id)
        textArea.setAttribute('cols', 1);
        textArea.setAttribute('rows', 3);
        textArea.onclick = createResizeFunction(textArea); // assign resize 
                                                           //function 
        elm.appendChild(textArea);
     }

     function createResizeFunction(textArea)  {
        var resize = function() {
           var id = textArea.id;
           // do something with that id
        };
        return resize;
     }
```